# Supremum of $a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}$ with $a+b+c+d=4$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a,b,c,d>0$ I want to find the supremum of :

> $$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}$$
>   With $a+b+c+d=4$

I claim that the supremum has the following form :
$$a^{ab}+3$$
With $a+b=4$

In fact it remains to prove the following theorem :

> Let $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $a+b+c+d=4$ and $a>b>c>d$ then we have :
>   $$a^{ab}+b^{bc}+c^{cd}+d^{da}< a^{ab}+3$$

All of this is just an intuition and I'm really stuck to prove this...

If you have hints it will be nice .

Thanks in advance for your time .

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: $(a, b, c, d) = (1.99, 1.1, 0.9, 0.01)$  is a counter-example for your “theorem.”

Comment: Some numerics: $a^{ab}$ has a max value of about 32.7037, for $a+b=4$ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+x%5E(4x-x%5E2),+x+from+0+to+4). So the desired supremum is at least 32.7037+3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is not true. I just generated 4 random numbers satisfying the condition $a+b+c+d=4$ and immediately found counter-examples.

Comment: A concrete counter-example would be more helpful ...

Comment: @PierreCarre Your counterexample does not satisfy the requirement $a>b>c>d$.

Comment: You are correct @ArnaudD. I'll remove or edit the counter-example.

Comment: $a=2.52799, b= 1.25971, c =  0.208747, d =  0.0035519$ is one counter-example obtained by simple simulation.